# PhpStorm keeps asking me to unlock my ssh private key

Tags: phpstorm

I have freshly installed PhpStorm on Ubuntu (19.04) and everytime I launch it, it asks me for my ssh private key passphrase. I click "Cancel" of course since I have no idea why it's asking me this in the first place so it keeps asking me once every few minutes.

The big problem is that in Ubuntu (unlike Mac OS) once you have unlocked a private key once, it stays unlocked for the current session. So of course, once I have unlocked my ssh private key once on the Terminal, PhpStorm stops asking me.

The only plugin I have installed on PhpStorm is ideaVim.

Anyone has an idea what could be causing this ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be better to contact PhpStorm support with this via Help > Contact Support. IDE logs should be inspected to check what might be causing this.